# Can you write to GCP PubSub with write only permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am creating a data pipeline in GCP. For some clients we want to have a publish only model (for security reasons). If read permissions is removed out of the default pubsub acl, will it impact writes in any way? What I am most worried about is that folks will be able to publish, but they may not be able to obtain any data that would tell them they should retry. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you mean with "but they may not be able to obtain any data that would tell them they should retry"? 

Are you worried perhaps of messages not being acknowledged? If so, as per what @guillaume blaquiere says in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952028/12232504), the publisher role would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation, you have a role for publishing and a role for subscribing.](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles). Simply grant the correct one to the service account used by the clients, and that's all!

Comment: Creating a custom role that allows for publishing only did the trick. Thank you!